# Tag manipulation using DOMDocument

Tags: php, symfony2

On our main symfony2 application at work I have had to manipulate some outputted grid fields by wrapping them in a hyperlink tag.  This happens in quite a few different controllers, so I made a method to do this to prevent code repetition.

I decided to do this using DOMDocument and construct the new hyperlink with that.

```
public function linkWrap($string, $route, array $route_params = [], $prefilter = null)
  {
    if(strlen($string) > 0)
    {
      $dom = new \DOMDocument();
      $new_hyper = $dom->createElement('a');
      $new_hyper->setAttribute('href', $this->generateUrl($route, $route_params).(isset($prefilter) ? '?'.htmlspecialchars($prefilter) : ''));
      $new_hyper->nodeValue = $string;

      return $dom->saveHTML($new_hyper);
    }

    return $string;
  }
```

The method takes a number of options the last of which is used only to append a prefilter query string for use with APYGridBundle.

My question is, does this cause a significantly larger overhead than just constructing the link in a more 'conventional' way?

As follows:

```
$link = "<a href=" . $this->generateUrl('a_route', array('id' => 23)) . '?'.$prefilter">some text</a>";
```

In addition, any tips on how any of could be improved would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Creating links using DOMDocument makes no sense to me.

I have created [a simple benchmark for both methods](https://github.com/bronek89/anchor-benchmark).

Simple string concatenation is around 7 times faster on my computer:

> ```
> Method Name          Iterations    Average Time      Ops/second
> ------------------  ------------  --------------    -------------
> simpleLink        : [10,000    ] [0.0000013786793] [725,331.85764]
> linkUseDomDocument: [10,000    ] [0.0000098103762] [101,932.89054]
> ```

You could reuse objects in (for example) static variables like this:

```php
public function linkWrap2($string, $route, array $route_params = [], $prefilter = null)
{
    static $dom = null, $new_hyper = null;

    if(strlen($string) > 0)
    {
        if ($dom === null) {
            $dom = new \DOMDocument();
            $new_hyper = $dom->createElement('a');
        }

        $new_hyper->setAttribute('href', $this->generateUrl($route, $route_params).(isset($prefilter) ? '?'.htmlspecialchars($prefilter) : ''));
        $new_hyper->nodeValue = $string;

        return $dom->saveHTML($new_hyper);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

but it's only 30% faster.

### My observations

Don't use `htmlspecialchars` in `setAttribute` value, because it will be encoded twice:

```php
$new_hyper->setAttribute('href', $this->generateUrl($route, $route_params).(isset($prefilter) ? '?'.($prefilter) : ''));
```

However, you must use `htmlspecialchars` in simple concatenated strings:

```php
$link = "<a href=" . $this->generateUrl('a_route', array('id' => 23)) . '?'.htmlspecialchars($prefilter).'">some text</a>';
```

Try to avoid custom query strings after a generated route URL. Instead of place value of `$prefilter` after the URL, you could place additional route params:

```php
$this->generateUrl($route, array_merge($route_params, [ 'prefilter' => $prefilter ]));
```